# Freezes when login, but not with another user

Tags: login

Until recently, whenever I login into my account, everything freezes after about 5 seconds. But, if I login into another user account, everything works fine.

What should I do? Is there any further information I should provide (sorry I don't know what I should and can give you)?

Comment: check your session configurations , e.g. `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, `.pam_environment` (these are all hidden files under your home directory). they may cause issues only relevant for a specific user.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you running some config data / setup which blocks your computer. I recommend instead of searching of the problem just to backup /home/(user) folder, create a completely new user profile and to copy ju"st data and some "." folders you absolutely need and delete the rest.

Folders beggining by "." contain init and config files to each piece of software you have and are often "invisible". Choose proper way to transfer all files and not to loose anything.

Comment: that's a bit of an overkill, isn't it?

Comment: yep, but without we know, what can cause that trouble and what is installed, this will work.

Comment: well, setting the computer or fire on installing windows (god forbid) will work as well, but our aim is to learn, right?